# while(multiple array lengths > 0)

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, do-while

I've found similar questions about my problem though the answers contain suggestions which do half of what I need - none of them do it all.

I need to develop a function which will cope with both:

1. an unknown number of arrays, AND...
2. of differing lengths AND...
3. **alternately** merge the arrays (added as edit)

I'm trying to write a function based on two I've found and believe I just need to figure the while() out, but I'm totally stumped. I can't seem to track down any examples of while loops that use an array in their conditions... if you follow.

---

```
function alternately_merge_arrays() {
  $arrays = func_get_args();
  $new_array = array();
  //

  while( count($array) in $arrays is > 0  ) {

  //
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
      if ( count($array) > 0 )
         $new_array[] = array_shift($array);
     }
  }
 return $new_array;
}

var_dump(alternately_merge_arrays(array(1,4), array(2,5,7), array(3,6,8,9));
```

---

Of course I may be completely wrong and it needs to be something other than a while() loop. I'm cool using for() and foreach(), though if the first array is the shortest these would stop looping where while() should continue...

Edit: The output I need would be:

```
array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Comment: Why not just do `while (count($arrays) > 0)` and remove the arrays that are/become empty in the inner loop?

Comment: Hi @Sami. Thank you for showing interest. `while(count($arrays) > 0)` is only counting the number of arrays supplied, not their lengths... which is what I need.

Comment: Yes, but if you remove the empty arrays within the inner loop then in the end it becomes empty itself and you know to stop. Until then it will contain non-empty arrays that you can loop through.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware ... so there is no way to do this? No pointers toward an alternative approach? Thank you for your interest btw

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen - ha! Of course! I get your drift... thank you, I will pursue this.

Comment: What you want is to end up with a single array product of merging all other arrays, with the same order?

Comment: Hi @gmc - yes indeed. Alternating, so the returned array in the above case would end up with all the numbers (1 to 9) in the correct numerical order.

Comment: OK. So then choose one of the proposed solutions for merging the arrays and after that, sort the result. It is not complicated at all

Comment: your question is obscure. Please describe what do you want your program to do. for example you can describe the result of the three arrays you took,

Comment: [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is already able to merge more than 2 arrays.

Comment: I've amended my question to, hopefully, make it clear what I was asking to anyone seeking help here in future and chosen the solution as requested here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
function alternately_merge_arrays() {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $new_array = [];
    while ($arrays) {
        foreach ($arrays as $key => &$array) {
            $item = array_shift($array);
            if ($item) {
                $new_array[] = $item;    
            } else {
                unset($arrays[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

The key changes are:

1. you don't need to use `count` just to see if an array is empty, because an empty array will evaluate to `false`.
2. If you use a reference (`&$array`), then `array_shift` will directly affect the array in question, so you can remove each array from `$arrays` if it has been emptied after removing an element with `array_shift`.

If you're using PHP 5.6+, then you can take advantage of [variable length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) (variadic functions) and use:

```
function alternately_merge_arrays(...$arrays) {
```

so you can forgo the `func_get_args` and still use it with a variable number of arrays.

Comment: Looks good. But $array should be a reference; otherwise it will be copied for each run of the while loop. ==> foreach($arrays as $key => &$array)

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I copied and pasted and ran it sending three arrays as above and got "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)". It identified the line `$new_array[] = array_shift($array);` as the problem (though I know this is not always accurate). Perhaps this is what @jh1711 is referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I had it right at first and then edited it into wrongness after second guessing myself. I just edited it back into rightness after actually testing it.

Comment: Thanks gang! I've just spent the last few mins putting it in my script and testing it with the actual arrays - works perfectly! Great team work! (I'm not on 5.6+, though thank you for the extra info)

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge more than 2 arrays? There are many ways to do that. This looks a bit like what you intended.

```
<?php

function alternately_merge_arrays() {
  $arguments = func_get_args();
  $result    = [];
  foreach($arguments as $argument) {
    if (is_array($argument)) $result = array_merge($result,$argument);
                        else echo "ERROR: argument is not an array.";
  }
  return $result;
}

var_dump(alternately_merge_arrays(array(1,4), array(2,5,7), array(3,6,8,9)));
```

The output is:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=> int(1)
  [1]=> int(4)
  [2]=> int(2)
  [3]=> int(5)
  [4]=> int(7)
  [5]=> int(3)
  [6]=> int(6)
  [7]=> int(8)
  [8]=> int(9)
}
```

Comment: Hi @kiko, thank you for this. The output isn't quite what I was after, though I see what you've done. Appreciated. I have up arrowed your answer though I don't have enough rep for it to show. It was registered, it said.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array with keys that gives the position of each value according to this simple format: `column#raw`. Then all you have to do is to sort by keys and return the values:

```
function alternately_merge_arrays() {
    $result = [];
    foreach(func_get_args() as $n => &$array) {
        foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
            $result["$k#$n"] = $v;
        }
    }
    ksort($result);
    return array_values($result);
}
```